# Halmos's definition of unions

Tags: set-theory

In Halmos's Naive Set Theory, he defines a "comprehensive set" $U$ for any collection $\mathcal{C}$ of sets. He starts with a definition he suggests could be "too comprehensive."

> For every collection $\mathcal{C}$ there exists a set $U$ such that if $x \in X$ for some $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$, then $x \in U$.

He comments that such a set many contain elements that belong to none of the sets $X$ in the collection, and rectifies it by defining the set as
$$\{x \in U : x \in X \text{ for some $X$ in $\mathcal{C}\}$}.$$

The only scenario that comes to mind where the first set is different from the second (as they sound incredibly similar) is that $\mathcal{C}$ may be the empty collection. Even thhen, it still seems that the sets are equivalent to me, so I'm struggling to see the difference.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the collection consisting of the sets $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$. Let $U=\{0,1,2\}$. Then $U$ satisfies the first description: the only elements of $\mathscr{C}$ are $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$, and if $x\in\{0\}$ or $x\in\{1\}$, then $x\in U$. But $U$ does not satisfy the second description: $2\in U$, but there is no $X\in\mathscr{C}$ such that $2\in X$, since $2\notin\{0\}$ and $2\notin\{1\}$.

Answer (score 5):

The first definition says that if $x \in X$ for some $X,$ then $x \in U.$

It **does not** say that if $x \in U,$ then $x \in X$ for some $X.$

So, for instance, the union of $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ is $\{1, 2\},$ but the set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ obeys the first definition.